# Pass list of file paths to a batch file to be copied from Location A to Location B

Tags: excel, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Beginner to batch files and running commands in cmd or PowerShell. Need help in writing a script and/or producing a batch file that will allow me to do the following:

1) Pull list (List1) of file paths (including the file name and where the file is saved currently) from ColumnA of Excel123.xslx and a list (List2) of new destination file paths from ColumnB of Excel123.xlsx (if needed, the file with the old path and destination path can be in CSV or any txt format)

2) Pass through the file paths from List1 and copy the file from the location in List1 to the new destination location in List2

In fewer words, I need to copy a file from the current location in List1 to the new destination location in List2. And, if the new destination location includes folders and sub-folders that do not exist yet, they need to be created in the process.

Any advice/insight? Thank you!

Comment: depending on the exact format of the Excel file (`.csv` needed for batch solutions) something along `for /f %%a in (excel123.csv) do copy "%%~a" "%%~b"` should do.

Comment: The csv file would just be file paths in Column A (i.e. C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\TestA.csv) and destination locations to copy the file over to in Column B (i.e. C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Dest\Tests\)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to essentially do as follows:

```
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_CSV_File=C:\Some\Path\FileList.csv"
)

FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=," %%A IN ('
  Type %_CSV_File% ') DO (
  ECHO: Copying FROM: "%%~A" TO: "%%~B"
  COPY /B /V /Y /Z "%%~A" "%%~B"
)

ENDLOCAL
```